# ¿De qué maneras puedo redireccionar en xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Estoy haciendo mi primera aplicación mobile de android y estoy con un problema "simple".

Tengo un menú a la izquierda con varios `<FlyoutItem/>` donde se redirecciona a todas las vistas que existen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahi funciona todo perfecto.

El problema viene cuando quiero iniciar sesión, resulta que cuando ingreso las credenciales correctas, me redirecciona al HomePage, pero no puedo acceder al menú con los `<FlyOutItem/>`
ya que tengo un botón que me redirecciona a al Login.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en cambio deberia tener esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La redirección la estoy haciendo así:

```
 private void btnLogin_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (EntryUsername.Text == "Admin" && EntryPassword.Text == "123")
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", "El Usuario o Contraseña es incorrecto!", "Ok");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Seguramente sea una tontería esto pero todos los ejemplos que vi hacen todo igual y llegan a donde llego yo.

También eh intentado

```
 Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
```

Ó

```
 Application.Current.MainPage = new HomePage();
```

Pero queda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola bro espero que hayas podido solucionar,
en caso que no, te indico:
1- Para ocultar el botón de la "flechita" que te devuelve a la página anterior, lo que tenés que escribir es lo siguiente en el *contentPage*:
**NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar=False**

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por la respuesta, pero deje ese laburo ya hace unos meses jajajajaj.

Comment: @BilbitBolson la cuestión es que tanto tu pregunta como sus respuestas sean de utilidad a otros usuarios con el mismo problema más adelante. No te responde a ti, sino al contenido de tu pregunta.